# Using JSON Data Without TItle to Change Text Box Value

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to alter the value of a textbox with JSON values retrieved from a PHP file. Unfortunately, my JSON array doesn't have a title. How can I select the data with which to alter the value?

My data:

```
[
    {
    id: 1027,
    title: "Latest",
    time: 1408588109727,
    description: "SADD meeting is at 2:00 on Friday",
    groupId: 1,
    schoolId: 1
    },
    {
    id: 1026,
    title: "SADD Meeting",
    time: 1408161600000,
    description: "SADD meeting is at 2:00 on Friday bucn of spaces ....",
    groupId: 1,
    schoolId: 1
    } ]
```

Here is my entire script:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var counter = 1;
                var textboxNum = '<?php echo $titlenum; ?>'; 
                parseInt(textboxNum);

                while (counter - 1 < textboxNum) { 

                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter); 
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                      '<input type="text" class="title"' +
                      '" id="title' + counter + '" value="" name="title[]">');  
                var newTextAreaDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                      .attr("id", 'TextAreaDiv' + counter);       
                newTextAreaDiv.after().html(
                      '<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="text"' +
                      '" id="text' + counter + '"value="" name="text[]" ></textarea>');       
                $('#Spacer')
                .prepend(
                   $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                       id:    'myCheckbox'  + counter
                      ,name:  'myCheckbox' + counter
                      ,value: 'myValue'
                      ,type:  'checkbox'
                   })

                );        
                newTextBoxDiv.prependTo("#Spacer");
                newTextAreaDiv.prependTo("#Spacer");
                counter++;      
                }
                $.getJSON( "jsonData.php", function( data ) {
                for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#title' + (i + 1)).attr('value', .data[i].title);
                }
                });

                $("#addButton").click(function () { 

                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter); 
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                      '<input type="text" class="title"' +
                      '" id="title' + counter + '" value="" name="title[]">');  
                var newTextAreaDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                      .attr("id", 'TextAreaDiv' + counter);       
                newTextAreaDiv.after().html(
                      '<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="text"' +
                      '" id="text' + counter + '"value="" name="text[]" ></textarea>');       
                $('#Spacer')
                .prepend(
                   $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
                       id:    'myCheckbox'  + counter
                      ,name:  'myCheckbox' + counter
                      ,value: 'myValue'
                      ,type:  'checkbox'
                   })
                );        
                newTextBoxDiv.prependTo("#Spacer");
                newTextAreaDiv.prependTo("#Spacer"); 
                counter++;

                 });
                $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 2) {
              alert("Can't remove any more textboxes");
              return false;
            }      
              $('[id^=myCheckbox]').each(function(i){
                  if($(this).is(':checked')){
                      var getlastId=$(this).prop('id').substr(10);
                      $("#TextBoxDiv" + getlastId).remove();
                      $("#TextAreaDiv" + getlastId).remove();
                      $(this).remove();
                      counter--;
                  }
              }); 
              });


            });

     </script>
```

And my HTML:

```
            <div id='TextBoxesGroup' width='800px'>
                <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="connor">
                <form role="form" method="post" form action="action.php">
                <div id="Spacer" width="800px" class="SpacerInput">
                    <input type="Submit" value="Save" id="saveButton" class="buttonThree">

                    <input type="button" value="Add" id="addButton" class="buttonOne">      
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Checked" id="removeButton" class="buttonTwo">
                    </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </body>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have a title? It's just an array, arrays don't have titles, whatever that means. You just loop over the array in the variable `data`. What is `json.data`?

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and raw DOM like that? Isn't `$('<div>', { id: 'TextBoxDiv'+counter}` easier?

Comment: I am beginner to Jquery, so I was simply following a tutorial. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The name of the variable containing the array is just `data`, not `json.data`. And when you're getting the title from the element, don't put quotes around it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "jsonData.php", function( data ) {
        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#form' + i + ' input[type="text"]').attr('value', data[i].title);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I added my entire script code, maybe you could look and see why it doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe use `.val(xxx)` instead of `.attr('value', xxx)`.

Comment: That didn't work either, unfortunately. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I don't see `<form id="form0">`, etc. in your HTML. What happened to the code that I was originally answering? If you want to show updated code, append it to the end of the question, don't remove the original code.

Comment: Excuse me, I completely forgot that I had taken that part of the code out for debugging In any case, I managed to make my code work by editing the PHP so that I could use this:

    `code$(document).ready(function(){
     $.getJSON( "jsonData.php", function( data ) {
     for(var i=0; i < data.posts.length; i++) {
     $('#title' + (i + 1)).val(data.posts[i].title);
     $('#text' + (i + 1)).val(data.posts[i].description);
     }
     });
    });`

Comment: Why don't you name your elements starting from 0 so you don't have to keep doing `(i + 1)`?